# How to pass value from a react native app to a node js backend

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, postman

I'm trying to pass datas to my back-end Node js server with my react native app.
And for that i'm using axios.

```
  onTrigger = () => {
    const params = JSON.stringify({
      "username": "Name",
      "password": "Pass",
    });
    axios.post('http://192.168.1.36:8080/api/signin',params)
    .then(function (response) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Principal')
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

But it's not doing nothing. My server is not detecting nothing.

But when i'm trying with postman with the same body and the same datas, it's working.

[image]

With Postman, i have a reaction from my server
[image]

I would like to know if anyone have an idea why my axios is not working but if i'm doing the same in postman, it's working.

Comment: `.then(function (response) {` try changing this to an arrow function `.then((response) => {` so you're accessing the correct `this`

Comment: *My server is not detecting nothing* Pink Floyd's fan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this. it works for me

```
      const params = JSON.stringify({
         "username": "Name",
         "password": "Pass",
        });       
        var config = {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://192.168.1.36:8080/api/signin',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data : params
        };
        
        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Principal')  
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: No it does not change anything. I have the impression that he does not receive what I try to send with axios

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

const apiClient = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.36:8080/,
timeout: 10000,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
});

const params = {
username: "Name",
password: "Pass",
});

apiClient.post('api/signin',params).then(() => {})

Comment: No :/ not doing nothing. But thx for the try :')